# Nested 'AND OR' Query in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm currently attempting to create a nested query, as follows:

```
public function getChallenge($user_id, $opponent_id)
{
    $challenge = $this->challenges()
            ->where('open', true)
            ->where(function($query) use ($user_id, $opponent_id) {
                    $query->where('player_1', $user_id)
                          ->where('player_2', $opponent_id);
                })
                 ->orWhere(function($query) use ($opponent_id, $user_id) {
                    $query->where('player_1', $opponent_id)
                          ->where('player_2', $user_id);
                })
            ->first();

    return $challenge;
}
```

This creates the following query for example:

```
select * from `site_challenges_leagues` 
where `site_challenges_leagues`.`league_id` = '1' 
and `open` = '1'
and (`player_1` = '3' and `player_2` = '1') 
or (`player_1` = '1' and `player_2` = '3') 
limit 1
```

However, this always returns the first value in the table (where `open` is either `1` or `0`), which is incorrect. For the query to be correct, it needs to contain both sets of `AND` queries in brackets, as follows:

```
 select * from `site_challenges_leagues` 
 where `site_challenges_leagues`.`league_id` = '1' 
 and `open` = TRUE 

 and ((`player_1` = '3' and `player_2` = '1') 
 or (`player_1` = '1' and `player_2` = '3'))

 limit 1
```

Is it possible to do this in Laravel? I attempted to do this; however, it failed:

```
public function getChallenge($user_id, $opponent_id)
{
    $challenge = $this->challenges()
            ->where('open', true)
            ->where(function($q) use ($user_id, $opponent_id) {
                $q->where(function($query) {
                        $query->where('player_1', $user_id)
                              ->where('player_2', $opponent_id);
                    })
                  ->orWhere(function($query) {
                        $query->where('player_1', $opponent_id)
                              ->where('player_2', $user_id);
                    })
                })
            ->first();

    return $challenge;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You were very close to the answer

```
$challenge = $this->challenges()
        ->where('open', true)
        ->where(function($q) use ($user_id, $opponent_id) {
            $q->where(function($query) use ($opponent_id, $user_id){
                    $query->where('player_1', $user_id)
                          ->where('player_2', $opponent_id);
                })
              ->orWhere(function($query) use ($opponent_id, $user_id) {
                    $query->where('player_1', $opponent_id)
                          ->where('player_2', $user_id);
                });
            })
        ->first();
```

[Here](http://www.diffchecker.com/97t6228l) are the differences between two codes

Answer (score 2):

I needed the nested wheres to search for a user by multiple fields:

```
    $users_query->where('company_uuid', '=', $company_uuid);
    $users_query->where('is_active', '=', true);
    $users_query->whereNested(function($query) use ($search){
        /** @var Builder $query */
        $query
            ->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    });
```

Supposing you want to stack `where` layers without losing them on using `orWhere`
Wouldn't this be the same thing ?

```
   $challenge = $this->challenges()
       ->where('open', true)
       ->whereNested(function($q) use ($user_id, $opponent_id) {
           $query->where('player_1', $user_id)
               ->where('player_2', $opponent_id);

           $query->orWhere('player_1', $opponent_id)
               ->where('player_2', $user_id);
   })->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use where then additional where and pass conditions as arrays.
Between two where is 'And' operation.
Inside the second where is 'Or' operation.

Example:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('status', 'value')->where([
    ['age', '>', '10'],
    ['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
])->get();
```