# Laravel MySQL query that have 'AND' and 'OR' inside one query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem while doing some `SELECT` query for making a "Search" method.
Here is my table structure
`table 'users':
name | varchar,
username | varchar,
role | enum[Admin, Owner, Cashier],
address | text`

I have made an ajax script that sends a parameter called `query` into my `Laravel Controller`. This `query` parameter contains input from the users searching for some data in my `admin.blade.php` page that only shows users having `Admin` role from the users' table. Here is my query:

```
$data = DB::table('users')
                        ->join('outlets','users.outlet_id','outlets.outlet_id')
                        ->where('users.role','Admin')
                        ->where('users.nama','like','%'.$query.'%')
                        ->where('users.username','like','%'.$query.'%')
                        ->orWhere('outlets.nama_outlet','like','%'.$query.'%')
                        ->orWhere('users.address','like','%'.$query.'%')
                        ->orderBy('users.user_id')
                        ->get();
```

You don't have to give attention to the `join`. The point of my problem is the query above returns also the user that has `Owner` and `Cashier` role. For example, I have an `Admin` named `John` and an `Owner` named `Jane`, and they both have the same address, like `New York`. When the user typed `New York` in the search box, the query above should return only `John`. But, in my case, it also returns `Jane`.

How must I do the query?

I hope you understand my question. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested 'AND OR' Query in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129117/nested-and-or-query-in-eloquent)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks a lot for your help @El_Vanja, sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use where query in the function as below.

```
$data = DB::table('users')
                ->join('outlets','users.outlet_id','outlets.outlet_id')
                ->where('users.role','Admin')
                ->where(function($q) use ($query) {
                    $q->where('users.nama','like','%'.$query.'%');
                    $q->orWhere('users.username','like','%'.$query.'%');
                    $q->orWhere('outlets.nama_outlet','like','%'.$query.'%');
                    $q->orWhere('users.address','like','%'.$query.'%');
                })->orderBy('users.user_id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Why do I get `syntax error, unexpected '}'` above `->orderBy('users.user_id')`?

Comment: Try edited code :)

Comment: Ah, I see, I forget the semicolon. Thanks for your time and help @Dilip Hirapara.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
            $data = DB::table('users')
                ->join('outlets','users.outlet_id','outlets.outlet_id')
                ->where('users.role','Admin')
                ->Where(function($query) use ($name){
                  $query->where('users.nama','like','%'.$query.'%')
                    ->orWhere('users.username','like','%'.$query.'%')
                    ->orWhere('outlets.nama_outlet','like','%'.$query.'%')
                    ->orWhere('users.address','like','%'.$query.'%');
                })                       
                ->orderBy('users.user_id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to Dilip Hirapara's answer and it fixes my problem. But I have to make Dilip Hirapara's answer as the best answer because he answered first. But anyway, thanks a lot.